# Kuenneth short exact sequence for K-homology

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, spectral-sequences, ring-spectra

Atiyah proved a Kuenneth short exact sequence for K-theory. I need one for K-homology, but can not find any reference in the literature. Do you know one?

Using general spectra stuff, one gets a Kuenneth spectral sequence for K-homology. The question is then, phrased this way, why this spectral sequence (in the case of K-homology) degenerates suitably to give rise to a short exact sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

Markus Land referred me to a remark on top of page 62 in his PhD thesis ( http://hss.ulb.uni-bonn.de/2016/4432/4432.htm ), where he argues why we have a short exact UCT sequence relating K- and L-theory.

The same arguments also apply to the Kuenneth formula for K-homology: since the graded ring $\pi_\ast(KU)$ has global dimension 1, the Kuenneth spectral sequence collapses on the $E_2$-page and gives rise to the sought short exact sequence.

The reason why $\pi_\ast(KU)$ has global dimension 1 is because $\pi_\ast(KU)$ is a Laurent polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ in one variable, and the category of graded modules over this is equivalent to the category $\mathtt{Ab} \times \mathtt{Ab}$.